# Is it possible to combine OpenTok and regular calls on mobile?

Tags: android, ios, opentok, tokbox

I'm building video chat application. I'm wondering is it possible to make/receive calls during video conversation using OpenTok.

The main point is to allow hear each other caller and video companion - some kind of conference.

I've read documentation for OpenTok, Android and iOS developers and didn't find anything helpful

I've tried to test this and there is no sound in video conversation while call is active. Looks like they use same sound input and output

I know this is a bad question, but I don't know how to make proper request to google or documentation

Answer (score 0):

There is no such connectivity right now, so, you cannot mix an OpenTok session, and a regular mobile phone call. You could be interested in inspecting connectivity with SIP networks:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/sip/

Comment: As Fran mentioned, you cannot mix an OpenTok session and a PSTN call directly, but you can use the OpenTok SIP Gateway and a SIP provider such as Plivo or Twilio to bridge the audio between a WebRTC connection to a PSTN line. You can find the examples here: [OpenTok-SIP-Samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-sip-samples)